# Properties not loading while using 2 context place holders

Tags: spring, spring-properties

I wrote a test class to read properties defined

```
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath*:config/TestOne.xml","classpath*:config/TestTwo.xml"
})
public class PropertyTest {
        @Value("${test.one:DEFAULT}")
        private String test;
        @Value("${test.two:DEFAULT}")
        private String test2;

        @Test
        public void TestProperty(){

                System.out.println(test + "," + test2);

        }

}
```

***TestOne.xml***

```
  <context:property-placeholder
                location="classpath*:/config/testone.properties"                
                ignore-unresolvable="true" order="1" />
```

***TestTwo.xml***

```
<context:property-placeholder
                location="classpath*:/config/testtwo.properties"               
                ignore-unresolvable="true" order="2" />
```

***testone.properties***

```
test.one=testone
```

***testtwo.properties***

```
test.one=testone

test.two=test
```

While running the Test, output is

testone,DEFAULT

it is not fetching test.two from property.

If I am not specifying the default value

```
@Value("${test.two}")
        private String test2;
```

Output is
testone,test

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

I fear that this problem: "two property placeholder and a default value" is not easy to solve, because it looks like the default value is already "triggerd" by the first `property-placeholder` so the second one does not "need" to set this property "again".

A workarround is to have only one `property-placeholder` with two config files and the highes order:

```
<context:property-placeholder
            locations="classpath*:/config/testone.properties,
                       classpath*:/config/testtwo.properties"                
            ignore-unresolvable="true" order="0" />
```

(attention: `locations` property instead of `location`)